# How to add value of guarded fields in database

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am using laravel 5.3 and in my custom model, I have some guarded fields like following.

```
protected $guarded = ['id', 'tnant_id', 'org_id', 'fac_id', 'slug', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
```

Now When I try to add record using following.

```
CUSTOM::create(['tnant_id'=>123]);
```

It returns me following error.

```
Field 'tnant_id' doesn't have a default value.
```

Setting field default value in table will not work because each time I am passing value and it is giving error for all guarded fields.

So how I can add guarded fields value in database? In update query, It is allowing to update but on create it gives error.

Comment: instead of `CUSTOM::create('tnant_id'=>123);` try `$custom = new CUSTOM(); $custom->tnant_id = '123'; $custom->save();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply can't. `Model::create(array $attributes = [])` is using method `fill(array $attributes = [])`, which, we may say, filter out all guarded attributes, so they will not be assigned. So in point of creation `tnant_id` will be null.

I come up with two ways of doing this:

**A**

1. create a new model instance
2. set your attribute
3. save (persist) it to dabase;

So:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->tnant_id = 123;
$model->save();
```

**B**
This is more likely update than create, but, might be useful for you.

1. Change your DB schema to allow null values for your attribute or put default value.
2. create model using Model::create()
3. set attribute & update.

So:
Assuming you are using migrations, in your migration file use:

```
Schema::create(..
   $table->integer('trant_id')->nullable();
   //OR
   $table->integer('trant_id')->default(0);
...);
```

*Note*: It's hard to say which one is more suitable for you use-case, but I see your attribute is called `trant_id`, which is some form of relation I guess, so I suggest you to take look at [Eloquent's relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships), which might be a better answer.